# Как правильно редактировать select поля в amocrm?

Tags: php, crm

Применяю вот этот метод - PATCH /api/v4/leads/custom_fields.
Проблема в том, что при изменении содержимого селект поля, оно полностью применяется только после полной перезагрузки страницы, если этого не происходит, то получается следующее:

- если пользователь сидит в самой сделке, и в это время произошло изменение селект поля, у него остаются старые значения, новые не показываются, сохранить также нельзя, хотя пишет, что сохранилось, на самом деле нет.
- если он находится просто в списках сделок, то при переходе в сделку селект поле обновляется новыми значениями, но чтобы сохранить надо перещелкивать значения, потому что с первого выбора кнопка сохранить не появляется.
  Что делать, как это решается?